# Julia alternative for Python Scooby

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I would like to get a report of my environment package versions and hardware resources like Scooby does in Python (image below), but for Julia, is there a package to do that?

[image]

Comment: Try `versioninfo()` and `import Pkg; Pkg.status()`

Answer (score 0):

(Credit: Dan Getz) Use `versioninfo()` and `import Pkg; Pkg.status()`:

[image: output of versioninfo and pkgstatus]